# Composite Key formation for a date range in Hyperledger Fabric V1.0

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918611/composite-key-functions-in-hyperledger) question, I also have a doubt.

 Suppose my composite key is formed with the fields `Owner_id~dateOfcreation`
and my keys are like:

> - Owner1~11-05-2017
> - Owner1~12-05-2017
> - Owner1~13-05-2017
> - ...
> - ...
> - Owner1~30-05-2017

Will it be possible for me to get states for a **`date range`** for example `Owner1~12-05-2017 to Owner~27-05-2017`?

In my understanding `stub.GetStateByRange(startKey,endKey)` will return the keys which are in lexical order, so it will not return the expected range.
Correct me if I am wrong.

I tried to re-arrange the keys like:

> - Owner1~2017_05_11
> - Owner1~2017_05_12
> - Owner1~2017_05_13
> - ...
> - ...
> - Owner1~2017_05_30

In this case if i use
 
`stub.GetStateByPartialCompositeKey('owner~year~month~day',[]string{"owner1","2017","05"})` it will return all the keys starting with these range. is it correct?

But here also I am not getting my exact output for a **`date range`**.

Can anyone suggest me the proper way to implement this. I think it is a common business scenario in the context of asset sharing, so please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know how it works, but I achived it without numbers. Also, could you try to put "Owner1" instead of "owner1", i.e. with the O in capital letters

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What you have achieved without numbers? Any why to make 'O' capital?

Comment: Hi! The method stub.GetStateByRange(startKey,endKey) functioned great for me. The keys for me where numbers combined with letters, like c999, o111. On the other hand, I asked you if you could try to pass the values of owner with the O in capital letters. In the example that you give, you pass the owner is in lowercase. Also, could you try if it works passing two literals (for example: stub.GetStateByPartialCompositeKey('Owner1~2017_05_11', 'Owner1~2017_05_30'))? What do you get like response?

Comment: Ya that small 'o' was a typo. Corrected now. And for stub.GetStateByPartialCompositeKey in API documentations it is mentioned that the first param should be a key_index not the value. So can't try this way I think. And regarding  stub.GetStateByRange, yes that is possible if it is in lexical order. But my data fetch is timestamp based so I cant give a perfect start and end key. Only number I am getting in this is timestamp, if I use it as key like Owner_longTimestamp, then stub.GetStateByRange will be a huge performance hit right?

Comment: I think that the key_index and a value are the same. You have to define two different key_index, and it gets the result that there are among them. I'm sorry if I'm not understanding you. Could you explain again wich is your issue?

Comment: no problems :) appreciating your suggestions and it is helpful to me since I am new to this. My requirement is like as shown in the example, I am creating assets everyday, and if I want to list the all assets created with in a date range how I will query it from ledger? For this I am really confused to design a perfect key. Thats my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the existing comments, adopted solutions and API specification, it is concluded that `stub.GetStateByPartialCompositeKey` is best suited API for this requirement. 

To fetch data only for a day, it can use ***rich query*** with json `date_field:value` also if it is using **CouchDB** as its state db. Since it is not a committing transcation no issue to use ***rich query*** here.

Answer (score 1):

After rereading your question and the comments, I think that you have your own solution for you. What about using the function GetStateByRange? This function doesn't return keys, it returns an iterator with the values.

As you said in your last comment, I want to list the all assets created with in a date range how I will query it from ledger. So, if I were you, I'd use the GetStateByRange function, passing to it the date range.

Here I paste you an example of a function that I used.

```
func get_all_components(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var err error
    fmt.Println("starting get_all_components")

    // input sanitation
    err = sanitize_arguments_len(args, 1)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    // ---- Get All Components ---- //
    resultsIterator, err := stub.GetStateByRange("c0", "c9999999999999999999")
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
    defer resultsIterator.Close()

    // buffer is a JSON array containing QueryRecords
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString("[")

    bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten := false
    for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
        //queryKeyAsStr, queryValAsBytes, err := resultsIterator.Next()
        queryResponse, err := resultsIterator.Next()
        if err != nil {
            return shim.Error(err.Error())
        }

        // Add a comma before array members, suppress it for the first array member
        if bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten == true {
            buffer.WriteString(",")
        }
        buffer.WriteString("{\"Key\":")
        buffer.WriteString("\"")
        buffer.WriteString(queryResponse.Key)
        buffer.WriteString("\"")

        buffer.WriteString(", \"Record\":")
        // Record is a JSON object, so we write as-is
        buffer.WriteString(string(queryResponse.Value))
        buffer.WriteString("}")
        bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten = true
    }
    buffer.WriteString("]")

    fmt.Printf("get_all_components:\n%s\n", buffer.String())

    return shim.Success(buffer.Bytes())
}
```

You should pass your **`date range`** values in the function call, in the args.

Comment: Yes. This is a good approach. So in my case to use stub.GetStateByRange("c0", "c9999999999999999999"), i need to create key like Owner1_<long_timstamp> right? Example to fetch data for 11-05-2017 00:00:00 to 10-06-2017 23:59:59 I need to use like stub.GetStateByRange("Owner1_<long timestamp of (first_date)>", "Owner1_<long timestamp of (second_date)>"). Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. Probably, it will work only passing the date but not the time, but I don't know. You would try it. Good luck.

Comment: One more doubt is stub.GetStateByRange("c0", "c9999999999999999999") how it is working internally. There will be any performance hit if range or number of data increases?