# What is the difference between create an index with compositeKey and a normal index?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

reading the Hyperledger Fabric documentation about index in couchdb I found two ways to create an index:

1. Create an index via CompositeKey function provide by stub e.g Marbles chaincode example:

   ```
   indexName := "color~name"
   colorNameIndexKey, err := stub.CreateCompositeKey(indexName, []string{marble.Color, marble.Name})
   ```
2. Create an index with Json format and save it in META-INF in order to be used in Rich Queries e.g:

   ```
   {"index":{"fields"["color","name"]},"ddoc":"indexColorName","name":"indexColor","type":"json"}
   ```

In both cases I can query the marbles by color-name, so my question is:

What is the difference between those two ways to create an index?

Comment: 1. is largely to do with chaincode 'states' see https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#createCompositeKey__anchor and also this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918611/composite-key-functions-in-hyperledger  on their use - ie searching by key  and

Comment: 2. Indexes in CouchDB are required in order to make JSON queries efficient and, in fact, are required for any JSON query with a sort specified - but you still need the query :-) (ie the matching CouchDB query (written in mango language) which would use the index as a means of search optimisation). But that rich query can be specified against non-composite key fields

Comment: Can you please, give me an example when I should use composite key and when I should use normal index?